# Utilise-t-on « rude » devant un nom avec un sens positif ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

Est-ce que l'adjectif « rude » est utilisé devant un nom avec un sens positif, similaire à «  grand » ou « fort » ? Si oui, pourriez-vous donner des exemples idiomatiques de telle utilisation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans l'expression :

> C'est un rude gaillard !

C'est un homme vaillant, puissant physiquement, courageux moralement.

Dans d'autres emplois, lorsque l'on parle de personnes *rudes* cela correspond plutôt à : *mal dégrossi, primitif avec une force naturelle*

Les synonymes sont alors : *fruste, grossier, brutal, bourru, redoutable*.

Comment: Frustre => fruste ? http://www.academie-francaise.fr/frustre-melange-de-fruste-et-de-rustre

Comment: @guillaume31 Exact - je me suis laissé 'embarqué' par *frustrer, frustration.*